# Cost of observe()

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider the following use of "observe":

```
database.child("\(email)/Data").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        ...
})
```

Is there a way to estimate how much data is downloaded/transferred during a 1 hour period of running `.observe` ? (Assume no changes have been made at `.child("\(email)/Data")` during the 1 hour period). How does it differ if observing on `.child(email)`? This is for the purpose of estimating Firebase realtime Database Bills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pay for the amount of data that is read/downloaded from the database, the cost depends purely and only on how large the data is that you observe, and how frequently it changes. Once you know those, you can stick them into the [pricing calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#blaze-calculator) and get a reasonable estimate of what your cost will be,

Comment: If you observe 10kb of data BUT that data never changes , will that cost you more than the price of 10kb?

Comment: You are charged for the data that is downloaded from the database. If you read 10KB once, you'll be charged for 10KB. The pricing is really not more difficult than that.